# Undefined name 'data'. - flutter

Tags: flutter

in my chat_detail.dart I'm getting this error. Im new to flutter. appreciate your help on this. these are the errors showing in terminal. below I have insert my chat_detail.dart code for your referance.

- Undefined name 'data'.
- The method 'Data' isn't defined for the type 'HtmlDocument'.
- Undefined name 'data'.

  ```
  import 'dart:html';
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
   import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   class ChatDetail extends StatefulWidget {
     final String friendUid;
     final String friendName;

     const ChatDetail(
         {Key? key, required this.friendUid, required this.friendName})
         : super(key: key);

     @override
     _ChatDetailState createState() => _ChatDetailState(friendUid, friendName);
   }

   class _ChatDetailState extends State<ChatDetail> {
     CollectionReference chats = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats');
     final String friendUid;
     final String friendName;
     final currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
     var chatDocId;
     var _textController = new TextEditingController();

     _ChatDetailState(this.friendUid, this.friendName);

     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       chats
           .where('users', isNotEqualTo: {friendUid: null, currentUserId: null})
           .limit(1)
           .get()
           .then(
             (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
               if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                 chatDocId = querySnapshot.docs.single.id;
               } else {
                 chats.add({
                   'users': {currentUserId: null, friendUid: null}
                 }).then((value) => {chatDocId = value});
               }
             },
           )
           .catchError((error) {});
     }

     void sendMessage(String msg) {}

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
           stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
               .collection("chats")
               .doc(chatDocId)
               .collection('messages')
               .orderBy('createdOn', descending: true)
               .snapshots(),
           builder: (BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasError) {
               return Center(
                 child: Text("Something went wrong"),
               );
             }

             if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
               return Center(
                 child: Text("Loading"),
               );
             }

             if (snapshot.hasData) {
               data = document.Data(); //define data
               return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                 navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                   previousPageTitle: "Back",
                   middle: Text(friendName),
                   trailing: CupertinoButton(
                     onPressed: () {},
                     child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.phone),
                   ),
                 ),
                 child: SafeArea(
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       Expanded(
                         child: ListView(
                           reverse: true,
                           children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                             data =document.data()!; //function call
                             return Container();

                           }).toList(),

                         ),),
                       Row(
                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                         children: [
                           Expanded(
                             child: CupertinoTextField(
                               controller: _textController,
                             ),
                           ),
                           CupertinoButton(
                             child: Icon(Icons.send_sharp),
                             onPressed: () => sendMessage(_textController.text),
                           )
                         ],
                       )
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               );
             }
             return Container();
           });
     }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`document` has a type `HtmlDocument`

Remove `import 'dart:html';`.